# Why are Linux file permissions so primitive?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

Why are Linux file permissions still so primitive and is this likely to ever change?

Each file/dir can only have an owner and group. This seems to make the following things extremely difficult to implement:

How can you make a file read only and not delete-able, but still give that user permission to write to its directory?

How can you restrict directories to only certain users with out having to create a group for every possible combination of users required? And having done that its useless anyway because anyone who creates a file doesn't get it's permissions inheretted, so every user has to explicitly change the permissions on every file they make just so others can edit it.

I have found myself having to modify my programs to set the permissions of a file to the directory where it is saved to just to avoid user frustration.

How do you handle these sorts of things on desktop systems with non power users?

Comment: Linux encourages `Implementation` and not `Policy` so that you can fine tune the permissions available to suit your system users. Normally, its a system Admin job to implement & maintain such policies. It would be a lot easier if you change complex permissions using script instead of `cmd`

Comment: AFIAK file-system primary task is to provide efficient storage, efficient access, minimal permissions. For full-blown access restrictions [please check](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/VALinux-kb/acls.html)

Comment: There are also ACL-based permission systems available http://www.ghacks.net/2010/01/28/further-control-of-linux-files-with-acl/

Comment: There are ways to make a file so it can't be changed without changing the usual permissions.

Comment: It would seem that the permissions as they are are a filesystem thing (not particularly a Linux thing). However, it seems that people tend to make filesystem permissions a certain way, if they're meant for use in Linux. I don't believe there's any reason it has to be that way, though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ACLs to have an advanced control on file and directory permissions.

An example (for Archlinux in this case) is here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Access Control Lists ? see the [setfacl](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_setfacl.htm) command for an overview.

The issue of inheriting incorrect permissions is discussed at [linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/how-to-setup-file-permissions-for-multiple-groups-users-that-use-windows-and-linux-841962/).  Below is a summary of the proposed solution.

```
#mkdir tech
#chown root:tech tech/
#chmod g+s tech/
#chmod 0750 tech/
#setfacl -d -m g:techAdmin:rwx tech/
#setfacl -m group:techadmin:rwx tech/
```

The above will create a new directory `tech` which is owned by the `tech` group.  The user group `techAdmin` will have access to read/write/create and `tech` group users will have read access.